# where is microsite content in new content builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, microsites

where is microsite content in new content builder?

I see microsites in the classic content but not in new content builder.

The only thing I see is microsite definition under interaction but not in new content builder.

Any advise?

Comment: Only place I see microsite is within the CloudPages module.

Comment: microsites in classic is actually a completely different (and soon to be sunsetted) item than Cloudpages in SFMC. BUT Cloudpages is the Content Builder equivalent and is what I would recommend using as I believe Classic and Microsite (in classic) will be sunsetted either the end of this year or next year.

Comment: To clarify - only classic email content is in the announced end of life schedule. Microsites will not be affected.